# Unable to update a field in database FMDB using SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

Here is my function in which I am trying to update a field `count` in my table. But it is not updating the value. Query is 100% fine as I have already tried it in external database software. May be I am using wrong function to execute my statement?

```
    func updateLocalCount(var localCounter: Int)
    {
        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if contactDB.open()
        {
            let querySQL = "UPDATE Darood SET count='\(localCounter)' WHERE title='\(myTitle)'"
            let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL,
                withArgumentsInArray: nil)
            print(querySQL)
            contactDB.close()
            print("local count \(localCounter)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
    }
```

Comment: execute the update query code?

Comment: what is your final query please put here

Comment: In your code where is `myTitle`?

Comment: `myTitle` is optional value to not?

Comment: this function executes on a button click event. myTitle is set in constructor. Final query becomes something like UPDATE Darood SET count='100' WHERE title='abc'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `executeUpdate`, not `executeQuery` for update queries. By calling `executeQuery` (and never calling `next`), you've simply prepared a query, but never performed it.

So, it might look like the following:

```
func updateLocalCount(counter: Int, title: String) {
    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    if contactDB.open() {
        defer { contactDB.close() }
        do {
            try contactDB.executeUpdate("UPDATE Darood SET count=? WHERE title=?", values: [counter, title])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } else {
        print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
}
```

---

In an unrelated observation, you'll notice that, above, I used the `?` placeholders in your SQL, not building SQL using string interpolation. You open yourself to a whole series of possible problems if you don't use placeholders.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rob! I wish I could give you 1000 up votes :)

Comment: how can i use replace function for update query.........

 try contactDB.executeUpdate("UPDATE reminder SET group_id = replace( group_id, '?', ?)", withArgumentsInArray: ["6", "''"])

Comment: Just remove the quotes around the `?` placeholders: `replace(group_id, ?, ?)`

Comment: Outstandingly......

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you are using `myTitle` as option value, if it is optional
try this

```
let querySQL = "UPDATE Darood SET count='\(localCounter)' WHERE title='\(myTitle!)'"
```

OR make `myTitle` mandatory field and assign empty `("")` as default value.
and then

```
let querySQL = "UPDATE Darood SET count='\(localCounter)' WHERE title='\(myTitle)'"
```

Comment: I have already made myTitle as mandatory field and assign ("") to initialize because myTitle later gets set before this function executes. And this is why I used let querySQL = "UPDATE Darood SET count='\(localCounter)' WHERE title='\(myTitle)'"

Comment: Can you please update the output you are getting by executing the query

Comment: Rob posted the correct solution, problem was in method. Anyway thanks for taking out time and looking into my problem :)